# How to send batch requests to C2DM (Android push service)?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

I am working on how to send push notification to c2dm. According to the documentation, I need to post the requests to c2dm one by one. If there is several thousands of push request, it will be a headache.

Is there any way to send batch requests like Apple push notification service ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

At present, Android C2DM does not provide batch messaging, and nothing has been announced.